# Vaadin 10 Charts size/resize problems

Tags: java, charts, vaadin

I made a vaadin 10 chart in Java. There seems to be multiple problems, all related to it's size. First, it's overflowing the screen, without me applying any size modifier or anything on it. Also, when I resize the screen vertically, eg, when I drag the chrome's inspect tool vertically, the chart becomes huge vertically, without even coming back to it's original size. Then, when I minimize the menu bar, it stays at the same size, but it should stay full size in it's container. However, only the container increases in width, not the chart itself. Here is some relevant code:

```
    chart.setTimeline(true);

    List<PageInfo> elementsMiseEnLigne = ListElementsMiseEnLigne();

    List<DataSeries> dataSeriesPerType = new ArrayList<>();

    List<DataSeries> flagsListSeries = new ArrayList<>();

    Configuration configuration = chart.getConfiguration();

    configuration.getChart().setType(ChartType.AREASPLINE);
    configuration.getChart().setBorderRadius(5);
    configuration.getChart();

    Navigator navigator = configuration.getNavigator();
    navigator.setEnabled(false);
    configuration.setTitle("Chronologie");


    RangeSelector rangeSelector = new RangeSelector();
    rangeSelector.setSelected(4);
    configuration.setRangeSelector(rangeSelector);

    configuration.getTooltip().setEnabled(true);
    chart.addClassName("TimelineElements-chart");


    int yAxisIncr = 0;

    for (PageInfo elementMiseEnLigne : elementsMiseEnLigne) {
        DataSeries elementsTypeDateSeries = new DataSeries();
        DataSeries flagsOnSeries = new DataSeries();

        dataSeriesPerType.add(elementsTypeDateSeries);
        flagsListSeries.add(flagsOnSeries);
    }
    ElementCampagne.elementMappingService = homePagePresenter.getElementMappingService();
    YAxis yAxis = new YAxis();


    yAxis.setOffset(0);
    yAxis.setMin(0);
    yAxis.
    configuration.addyAxis(yAxis);
    dataSeriesPerType.get(0).setName(TITLE_BANDEAU);
    dataSeriesPerType.get(1).setName(TITLE_EMPLOI);
    dataSeriesPerType.get(2).setName(TITLE_NEOTV);

    int i;
    for (ElementCampagne elementMel : elementMels) {
        //...
        //Adding elements to dataSeriesPerType 
        //...
    }

    for (DataSeries dataSerie : dataSeriesPerType) {

        configuration.addSeries(dataSerie);
    }

    Legend legend = new Legend();
    legend.setAlign(HorizontalAlign.RIGHT);
    legend.setVerticalAlign(VerticalAlign.TOP);
    legend.setShadow(true);
    configuration.setLegend(legend);
```

Here are some screenshots:

[image: Img1]

[image: Img2]

[image: Img3]

Comment: Hi Etienne, please which version of Charts is this? I mean the exact version number printed by e.g `mvn dependency:tree | grep vaadin-charts-flow`. Can you try version `6.1.0-beta1`?

Comment: Even better, please try version `6.1.0`

Comment: Yes, switching to 6.1.0 fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: I will make my comment into an answer to help anyone googling this same problem.

Answer (score 2):

In version [6.1.0](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-charts-flow/releases/tag/6.1.0), Vaadin Charts addressed some sizing issues in flex containers. If you are using a 6.0.x version, upgrading should fix the issue.